# Button In FrameLayout ==> Change y? Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button in my FrameLayout.
When the user selects the button i need to bring the button a little bit higher, so decrease it's y.
How can i do this in code?

Comment: What language? What platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try adding some [padding](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding) inside an [onClick listener](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)).